# videoZoomFactor not working for a AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

There is still a problem with the zoom that I am struggling with. I try to acquire an image using the AVCaptureSession following the code from [link1](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273) and [link2](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297).

It all works very nicely except as soon as I try to implement a camera zoom, things do not perform as I wish.

I try to use the videoZoomFactor method on a AVCaptureDevice object as can bee seen in my Code below.

Do you have any suggestion why the videoZoomFactor does not have any effect ??

How would you create a zoom for a still image acquisition using the AVCaptureSession as intended ??

```
- (void)addVideoInput {
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (videoDevice) {

        // SOMEHOW NOT HAVING AN EFFECT AT ALL - WHY ?????
        if ([videoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
            float zoomFactor = videoDevice.activeFormat.videoZoomFactorUpscaleThreshold;
            [videoDevice setVideoZoomFactor:zoomFactor];
            // [videoDevice setVideoZoomFactor:3];
            // videoDevice.videoZoomFactor = 3;
            [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
        }

        // that all works again nicely...
        NSError *error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self captureSession] canAddInput:videoIn]) {
                [[self captureSession] addInput:videoIn];
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all formats support zooming. 
If you print your current format

```
NSLog(@"Current format: %@, max zoom factor: %f", videoDevice.activeFormat, videoDevice.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor);
```

you'll probably get something like this (without zoom level).

```
Current format: <AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1559b3a0 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 720, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:49.240>, max zoom level: 1.000000
```

then if you print all formats

```
NSLog(@"All formats: %@", videoDevice.formats);
```

you'll notice that some of them have and some do not have zoom factor

```
All formats: (
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556aef0 'vide'/'420v'  192x 144, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f4e0 'vide'/'420f'  192x 144, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f3e0 'vide'/'420v'  352x 288, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:61.260, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f3f0 'vide'/'420f'  352x 288, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:61.260, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f360 'vide'/'420v'  480x 360, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f370 'vide'/'420f'  480x 360, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556ae30 'vide'/'420v'  640x 480, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556ae40 'vide'/'420f'  640x 480, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:64.000, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f5c0 'vide'/'420v'  960x 540, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:58.460, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f5d0 'vide'/'420f'  960x 540, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:58.460, binned>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f3a0 'vide'/'420v' 1280x 720, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:49.240>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556f3b0 'vide'/'420f' 1280x 720, { 1- 30 fps}, fov:49.240>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556aa60 'vide'/'420v' 2592x1936, { 1- 15 fps}, fov:64.000, max zoom:121.00 (upscales @1.00)>",
    "<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x1556aa70 'vide'/'420f' 2592x1936, { 1- 15 fps}, fov:64.000, max zoom:121.00 (upscales @1.00)>"
```

in my case last two has max zoom. In this case I'm setting for my activeFormat to last one (which has max zoom bigger than 1 (1=no zoom)). You shouldn't take it as in my example (lastObject), you should first check which format has zoom bigger than 1.

```
videoDevice.activeFormat = [videoDevice.formats lastObject];
```

Now you can set any number between 1.0 and videoMaxZoomFactor.

```
[videoDevice setVideoZoomFactor:5.0];
```

Comment: thank you zvjerka24 ! Wasn't aware of the different "activeFormat". The working-code I posted today still does not mention the activeFormat. Therefore I am not quite sure why this code works but not the original one of my post on 4.August... ? When and how does activeFormat get defined if it is not set explicitly (what is the default value) ?

Comment: Not sure what iKKAvCamViewController is doing. Maybe taht view controller is setting activeFormat or something!?
I was reading documentation, but didn't find anything that talks about default value. I'm pretty sure that depends on device hardware. If I find more on this I'll let you know ;)

Comment: Test above is on iPhone4. I just checked on 4S and it differ. Definitely because of hardware. 4S has stronger camera and default format is stronger than one for 4 (but again with max zoom level 1.0). In 4S best zoom level (in best quality) is 153.00.

Answer (score 0):

Have it working now with the following code :

```
dispatch_async(sessionQueue, ^{
    [self setBackgroundRecordingID:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [iKKAvCamViewController deviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferringPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

    if ([session canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
    {
        [session addInput:videoDeviceInput];
        [self setVideoDeviceInput:videoDeviceInput];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Why are we dispatching this to the main queue?
            // Because AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is the backing layer for AVCamPreviewView and UIView can only be manipulated on main thread.
            // Note: As an exception to the above rule, it is not necessary to serialize video orientation changes on the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer’s connection with other session manipulation.

            [[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)[self interfaceOrientation]];

            // Apply initial VideoZoomFactor to the device
            NSNumber *DefaultZoomFactor = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:3.0];
            NSError *error = nil;
            if ([[[self videoDeviceInput] device] lockForConfiguration:&error])
            {
                [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] setVideoZoomFactor:[DefaultZoomFactor floatValue]];
                self.zoomFactorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [DefaultZoomFactor floatValue]];
                [[[self videoDeviceInput] device] unlockForConfiguration];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }                
        });
    }
});
```